Eigenspace of sum of outer product.
I am investigating the eigenspace of the matrix:
$$ \frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k \mu_i \mu_i^T + \sigma^2I \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$$
where $k < d$.
I want to ask if the eigenspace $V_k$ spanned by the largest $k$ eigenvectors of this matrix satisfies that
$$V_k = \text{span}\{\mu_1, \cdots, \mu_k\}.$$

The answer to this question is obviously yes in the case that the $\mu_i$ are mutually orthogonal, since each $\mu_i$ would be an eigenvector in this case.
Your statement is not true in all cases, but it is true in the case that the vectors $\{\mu_1,\dots,\mu_k\}$ are linearly independent, which I will assume.
For the other case, it is helpful to note that the eigenspaces of your matrix $M = \frac 1k \sum_{i=1}^k \mu_i\mu_i^T + \sigma^2 I$ are the same as the eigenspaces of $A = M - \sigma^2 I = \frac 1k \sum_{i=1}^k \mu_i\mu_i^T$, with an eigenspace associated with $\lambda$ for $M$ is associated with $\lambda - \sigma^2$ of $A$. Thus, it suffices to consider the eigenvectors associated with the $k$ largest eigenvalues of $A$.
It now suffices to observe/show the following:

$A$ is positive semi-definite (symmetric with non-negative eigenvalues)
$\text{span}\{u_1,\dots,u_k\}$ is the column space of $A$ (or equivalently, you could prove that $\text{span}(A)^\perp$ is the entire nullspace of $A$)
The column space of $A$ is the span of the eigenvectors of $A$ associated with non-zero (and hence positive) eigenvalues.
$\text{span}\{u_1,\dots,u_k\}$ is the span of the eigenvectors associated with the $k$ largest eigenvalues (up to multiplicity), so the same must be true for $M$.

